# Do constraints have any effect when globbing in Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a site that used to have a load of blog posts on at URLs like either of these:

```
/blog/2014/03/21/post-name
/2014/03/20/another-post
```

They have now moved to a new domain and I'm trying to set up redirects in the routes file:

```
match '*path' => 
  redirect{ |params, request|
    "http://ournewdomain.com/#{params[:path]}"
  }, constraints: { :path => %r{(blog/)?\d\d\d\d/\d\d/\d\d/[\w\-_]+} }
```

But this is redirecting *all* requests to the new domain - it's as if the `constraints` has no effect. I've read [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7924) but it looks like that issue was resolved? Does `constraints` work with globbed routes?

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight tweak to this, and it seems to work:

```
  get '*path', to: redirect {|params, req| 
     "http://ournewdomain.com/#{params[:path]}" },
     constraints: { :path => %r{(blog/)?\d\d\d\d/\d\d/\d\d/[\w\-_]+} }
```

Comment: I'm going blind - what's changed? (Won't have a chance to check until Monday now unfortunately.)

Comment: It still redirects other URLs for me - the constraints seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to make the `constraints` on the globbed path work properly, I've currently ended up doing this, which seems clunky, but works:

```
match '/:year/:month/:day/:slug',
  to: redirect{ |p, request|
    "http://ournewdomain.com/#{p[:year]}/#{p[:month]}/#{p[:day]}/#{p[:slug]}/"
  }, constraints: {
        :year => /\d\d\d\d/,
        :month => /\d\d/,
        :day => /\d\d/,
        :slug => /[\w\-_]+/ }

# Same as above but with /blog/ prefix.
match '/blog/:year/:month/:day/:slug',
  to: redirect{ |p, request|
    "http://ournewdomain.com/#{p[:year]}/#{p[:month]}/#{p[:day]}/#{p[:slug]}/"
  }, constraints: {
        :year => /\d\d\d\d/,
        :month => /\d\d/,
        :day => /\d\d/,
        :slug => /[\w\-_]+/ }
```